# match values between two dictionaries, extract the keys with equals value in new dictionary

Tags: python

For example, I have:

```
dict1 = {"name":"Cristian","surname":"Rossi","nationality":"Italy","color":"red"}
dict2 = {"country":"Italy","loc":"Milan","other":"red","car":"ford"}
```

dictionaries is large, some thousands elements.
In this example, the values in both dictionaries are Italy and red. So, I would this result

```
dict3 = {"nationality":"country","color":"other"}
```

It may be easier to convert the dictionaries into sets?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get a set of the common values in both dictionaries. Then get the keys for those values and build a dictionary.

```
dict1 = {"name":"Cristian","surname":"Rossi","nationality":"Italy","color":"red"}
dict2 = {"country":"Italy","loc":"Milan","other":"red","car":"ford"}

common = set(dict1.values()) & set(dict2.values())
keys1 = [k for k,v in dict1.items() if v in common]
keys2 = [k for k,v in dict2.items() if v in common]

d = {k1:k2 for k1,k2 in zip(keys1, keys2)}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'nationality': 'country', 'color': 'other'}
```

Comment: It's unclear if this is possible with the OP's data, but worth noting this would not work if the same value appeared in multiple keys for one of the dicts. Try with `dict2 = {"country":"Italy","loc":"Italy","other":"red","car":"ford"} `

Comment: @totalhack OP needs to clarify but the values seem to be distinct within each dictionary. `loc` seems to be town/city name, not country name.

Comment: that was just a random example to show the behavior, not making any claims about the range of values in specific keys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach which first inverts the dicts and then looks at an intersection of the values. Given that intersection of values it then builds a final result with all of the keys that each value mapped to in the original dicts. Assumes Python 3.

```
d1 = {"name":"Cristian","surname":"Rossi","nationality":"Italy","color":"red"}
d2 = {"country":"Italy","loc":"Milan","other":"red","car":"ford"}

def inv_dict(d):
    inv = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        inv.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
    return inv

id1 = inv_dict(d1)
id2 = inv_dict(d2)
result = {v:id1[v] + id2[v] for v in id1.keys() & id2.keys()} 

print(result)
# {'Italy': ['nationality', 'country'], 'red': ['color', 'other']}
```

The output is slightly different than what you specified, but it's unclear how your example output would work if the same value appeared in multiple keys in one or both dicts.